# Execute a java program without setting the classpath

Tags: java, macos, terminal, classpath

I have a program that resides in a directory that is not set in the path/classpath - and I want to execute it using the `-cp` option on my console. But I get the `NoClassDefFoundException`, regardless of what I set as `-cp`

```
- out
 `- de
  `- my
   `- package
    `- MainClass.class
```

I navigate into the `package` directory and try to execute the main class using

```
MyBook-Pro:out flopes$ java -cp . de.my.package.MainClass
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Execute the same command from the `out` directory.

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath must contain

- jar files
- directories containing the roots of the package tree.

If your package is `de.my.package`, the root is `de`, and the directory containing `de` must be in the classpath.

So, if you're in the `package` directory, the classpath should be set to `../../..`: the `out` directory is the one that should be in the classpath.

Or you should use `.` as the classpath, but launch your program from the `out` directory.